# Windows Server Destination NAT

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-server-2019, rras, dnat

I'm unsure of the terminology for this question. Trying to solve a problem, I'm being forced to grow and learn something very new to me! How would I do Destination NAT on Windows Server 2016/2019 for an IP address? Is RRAS part of the solution, and how would I set this up?

- MyServer= 172.1.1.10
- RemoteDeviceReal= 10.1.1.20
- RemoteDevicePublic= 172.2.2.20

Talking with a linux expert, they would use something like this with iptables

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 10.1.1.20  -j DNAT --to-destination 172.2.2.20
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 172.2.2.20 -j SNAT --to-destination 10.1.1.20
```

Besides using some kind of NAT Proxy, what other solutions can I/should I look at?

any suggestions or hints that I could look up that would point me in the right direction. Is this even possible?

Comment: the trafic coming into MyServer is seen as coming from RemoteDeviceReal. But the only way to get communicate is by replying back using RemoteDevicePublic.

Comment: Is Windows even capable of this at all? Why are you trying to use Windows as a router? Why aren't you using IPv6?

Comment: We are trying to have an application manage a device in our client's network. That remote device only supports IPv4. Does Windows even support tis is one of my questions...

Answer (score 0):

You talk abou RemoteDeviceReal and RemoteDevicePublic. So there is something doing NAT between them. Is *this* router you are trying to configure, or is everything remote (from your point of view)?

If everything is remote and you can only see the *public* IP address of the remote router, there is nothing you can do on your end, whatever OS you are using.